# What is the difference in meaning between "offer" and "offering" when used as nouns in business situations?

Tags: difference

Can you please tell what is the difference in meaning between *offer* and *offering* when used as nouns in business?

We might find a good **offer**/**offering** at Progressive.

I've tried to find an explanation on the web, but there seems to be none.

Comment: The most likely definitions in a business context are: [Offering](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offering): "something offered for sale or patronage" (as in "we have a wide variety of financial offerings") and [Offer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/offer): "a price named by one proposing to buy : BID." Also, especially around hiring, an "offer" can be an offered salary amount.

Comment: Your example sentence is not grammatical.  You can't say "There might find".  It doesn't make sense.  Perhaps you mean "We might find".  Also what do you mean by "Progressive". Is this the name of a company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An 'offering' tends to refer to something more tangible than an 'offer'. It can refer to something that has already been given, or prepared.

Fur example, you might 'offer' to do something, and if your offer is rejected you never have to actually do it. You could also 'make an offer', which means to state an amount you are willing to pay or to give a description of something you are willing to give. Again, if the offer is turned down, you pay nothing or do nothing.

- The company put an offer of a pay rise on the table.
- He made an offer to look after my dog.

But if you 'make an offering', it means you present something already prepared to someone. An offering can also refer to items available, for sale even.

- Coldplay's last album was better than their latest offering.
- He brought a bottle of whiskey as a peace offering.